# i don't input any accounts but in still logs in

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
            Connections.con.Open();      

            string login = "SELECT ID, Username, [Password] FROM Employee";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(login, Connections.con);
            command.Connection = Connections.con;   
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtLUser.Text.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@?", txtLPass.Text.ToString());
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;                
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
                break;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.");
                this.Close();
            }  
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Username or Password");
            }

            Connections.con.Dispose();
            Connections.con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Thank you for using this Simple Login/Registration Form.");
        }
```

It always Logs in whenever i click Login Button and i haven't even typed anything in the user/pass textbox and there is no blank registered in my access database
any advice?

Comment: You missed where attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed where attribute

```
string login = "SELECT ID, Username, [Password] FROM Employee where Username=@? and [Password]= @? ";
```

Comment: OMG! how did i forgot that! Much Appreciated for the help Sir.. tomorrow is our presentation of this simple system and this is the only problem im facing whew! thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually *checking* the username and password.  Look at the database query:

```
"SELECT ID, Username, [Password] FROM Employee"
```

This will select *every* record from the `Employee` table.  Then you check those records:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    count = count + 1;
    break;
}

if (count == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.");
    this.Close();
}
```

According to this logic, as long as *any record exists* in the `Employee` table, the login is successful.

You *probably* want to check only for records which *match* the supplied credentials.  Something like this:

```
"SELECT [ID], [Username], [Password] FROM [Employee] WHERE [Username] = @? AND [Password] = @?"
```

(I'm guessing on the parameter syntax based on how you add the parameters, since I'm not familiar with MS Access syntax.  But hopefully you get the idea.)

Also, and **this is important**, you appear to be storing user passwords in plain text.  This is *an extremely terrible thing to do*.  Please hash passwords appropriately so that they can't be read as plain text.

Additionally, you appear to be using a *shared* connection object:

```
Connections.con.Open();
```

This is going to cause a whole host of problems.  It's a lot simpler and more stable to create the connection object within the scope of the method which uses it.  Basically, a connection object should be created, used, and disposed in a very tight scope and should not leak outside of that scope.

Comment: should i dispose the connection before closing it?

Comment: @JoeyEguna: No. While that *particular* object may *coincidentally* be able to handle that order of events (I don't know for certain), it's not a good idea. When an object is being disposed, it shouldn't be considered usable for any purpose. So no further methods should be called on it. You can avoid having to call `Dispose()` at all by wrapping it in a `using` block.  Something like: `using (var connection = OleDbConnection()) { // use the connection }`  A `using` block automatically disposes an object when it falls out of scope.